# Is a function atomic in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, atomic, mysql-function

I created `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num int
);
```

Then, I inserted the row whose `num` is `2` as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (2);
```

Then, I created `my_func()` function which updates `num` to `5`, then causes error by [SIGNAL statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html) as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  UPDATE test SET num = 5;
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
  RETURN NULL;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` gets the error, then `num` was rollbacked to `2` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT my_func();
ERROR 1644 (45000): An error occurred
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
```

Actually, I created `my_proc()` procedure which updates `num` to `5`, then causes error by `SIGNAL` statement as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc() 
BEGIN
  UPDATE test SET num = 5;
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, calling `my_proc()` gets the error but `num` is not rollbacked to `2` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> CALL my_proc();
ERROR 1644 (45000): An error occurred
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
```

So, is a [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) atomic in MySQL?